# How to solve this? []

Tags: javascript

why this problem occurs.I am added a tag element(number) in Hoursdiv through
dynamically.but the problem is:- element is not added in proper way.after added 6
element, space created.

javascript code:-

```
for(var i=1 ; i<=12; i++) {
    (function () {
        var cc=i;

        if(cc<=9)
            cc='0'+i;

        var _id1 = "time"+cc;
        str1 += "<a  id='"+_id1+"' class='hournum a_Cal' >"+cc+"</a>";
    }());
}
```

css code (*h2ooooooo edit note: I have no idea if `'a_cal'` is actually in the css file, but I've kept it here in case*):

```
'a_cal'
.a_Cal{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    width: 18%;
    height: 11%;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.hournum{
    padding:5px;
}
.hoursdiv{
    border: 1px solid #6699FF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 4%;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
    width: 45%;
    height: 52%;
    background-color: white; 
}
```

Comment: please, edit the title with something more specific, and reproduce this behaviour on a fiddle -> www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: what do you mean a space is created? your width is 18% times that by 6 that will be 108% so you can only have up to 5 elements on one line before it starts breaking to new lines.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fQNsr/

Comment: output of above code is first row 1 2 3 and second row  4 5 6 third row _ 7 8 and fourth row 9 10 11 like this. but i want number in  first row 1 2 3  second row  4 5 6 third row  7 8 9 fourth row  10 11 12

Comment: after fixing the invalid css on the fiddle (you had 'a_cal' at the top which stopped it from working, http://jsfiddle.net/fQNsr/2/) each element are spaced evenly and correctly, no space.

Comment: You should tell in which browser this happens and what `doctype` you have set. Most likely the browser you test in does not handle the `height`, `width` and `padding` in conjunction with the `float` on the `a` correctly. Which could cause incorrect distribution of the elements along the rows you have described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, I feel dirty looking at your code.
If your problem is that space on the right side of the container then let me explain what's going on.

The reason that space is there is because the 6th element is too wide to stay on the same "row", and it gets pushed down to the next row. The reason it's too wide is because of the combined use of %-width and padding in your css, which never ends well.

**Illustration**

[image: demonstration]

I've constructed an example of how I think you want it to look.
I also cleaned your code a little ;)

---

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BvCqc/) | Code

In this example I use absolute values instead of percentages. The benefit from this is that I can calculate the exact width required for my container.
A link's width is the sum of the width + padding + margin + border:

```
40 + (5*2) + (2*2) + (1*2) = 56 px
```

And we want 5 links per "row"

```
56 * 5 = 280 px
```

So the container's width has to be at least 280px to fit 5 links per row.

- CSS

```css
.hournum{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    width: 40px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 2px 2px;
 }

.container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 280px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #6699FF;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

- Javascript

```
var str = "";

for(var i=1 ; i<=12; i++){
    var cc = i;
    var row

    if(i <= 9) cc = "0" + i

    str += '<a href="#" id="time_'+cc+'" class="hournum">'+cc+"</a>";
 }

document.body.innerHTML = '<div class="container">'+str+"</div>";
```

**Result**

[image: result]

Comment: thanks ShadowScripter.it's working.i have use only hournum code part.and it's work corretly